# KDE keyboard shortcut to maximize a window

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts, opensuse, window

According to [*KDE Documentation → Common Keyboard Shortcuts → Panning and Zooming*](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/khelpcenter/fundamentals/kbd.html#kbd-activity-pan-zoom) there are 4 keyboard shortcuts for resizing/panning a window, where <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>◀─</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>─▶</kbd> also move the window to another monitor in a multi-monitor environment.

However, is there really no shortcut to maximize a window on the screen it's currently located on? Can such a shortcut be configured somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> switches between *maximized* and *windowed*/*restored* size.

I filed [an according bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=459672) and it has been resolved and fixed in the documentation source already.

Answer (score 5):

Simply searching for "maximize" in shortcuts settings shows the shortcut you're looking for.

The default is Meta + Page Up.

Comment: Searching for "maximize" on the page I linked in the Q yields nothing...yet. I filed [a bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=459672) and it has been resolved and fixed in the source already.

Comment: Yes, the documentation doesn't show it for me either. What I meant is that you can search directly in the shortcuts settings.

Answer (score 0):

**The documentation page has moved.**

Look here for [**Panning and Zooming**](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/khelpcenter/fundamentals/kbd.html): [KDE Documentation](https://docs.kde.org/) → [khelpcenter](https://docs.kde.org/index.php?language=en&package=khelpcenter) → [KDE Fundamentals / Stable (Frameworks 5)](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/khelpcenter/fundamentals/index.html) → [Common Keyboard Shortcuts](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/khelpcenter/fundamentals/kbd.html)

Or use your system:
Open Application Launcher > System Settings > Shortcuts

Then type **kwin** to view all shortcuts or **max** for *maximize window* in the search bar. Here you can customize the shortcut *maximize window* / *restore window* <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to another if you like.